# UI not redrawing after display powered off on Win 7

Tags: .net, wpf, windows-7

Some portions of my application's interface are not getting refreshed after Windows 7 powers down the display. More specifically, I'm swapping out images, User Controls, and a button's content while the display is powered off and after it has been restarted, and this isn't being reflected in the UI until I minimize and restore the window or move it to one of the screen's edges.

I've tried calling the Window's [InvalidateVisual()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.invalidatevisual.aspx) method when the app was in a state where it needed to redraw, and that didn't solve the problem. I have only been able to reproduce this issue on Windows 7. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I've seen stuff like this happen with dodgy video drivers.  Have you tried updating your video card's driver to the latest version?

Comment: The Device Manager states that the driver is up-to-date. We've also seen this on a few different machines running Win7

Comment: I've also seen similar things with dodgy ACPI drivers on XP - are those up to date? (Don't trust the device manager to know if there's a new version available...)

Comment: The ATI driver install is causing my machine (Win7 x64) to BSOD at the moment, so I think I'm going to have to trust the Device Manager on this one :)

However, this is consistently reproducible with different hardware configs (running the latest NVIDIA/ATI drivers,) so this is either a non-driver issue or incredibly pervasive driver issue requiring some kind of special workaround.

Comment: Now that's just strange if the WHQL certified driver is BSOD'ing your computer.  It may be a hardware issue of some sort...  I guess you've tried it on other machines?  If so, you should probably report this to MSFT as a bug.